# Microsoft-hosted agent - specify a different region than organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I see that azure Microsoft-hosted build agents are allocated in the same geography as the Azure DevOps organization. However, is there anyway to request for Microsoft hosted build agents to be allocated in a different region?

Our issue is, that our Azure DevOps organization is in region eastus2, where offices are in US, EU and AU. For test setups we get resources from azure on the go. ex. rabbitmq containers. Different offices maintain their own subscriptions and maintain different resource groups in the same regions closer to their offices.
Given that, we observe if a one in AU setup a pipeline to use a rabbitmq container it is allocated in the same region as the resource group, where Microsoft hosted agents in US, tests timeout.
But if we change the resource group to EU/US or the resource to EU/US, tests do not timeout. Given, each office prefers to have their resources in the same region as the office, is there any suggestion to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking)

> Your hosted agents run in the same Azure geography as your organization. Each geography contains one or more regions. While your agent may run in the same region as your organization, it is not guaranteed to do so. To obtain the complete list of possible IP ranges for your agent, you must use the IP ranges from all of the regions that are contained in your geography. For example, if your organization is located in the United States geography, you must use the IP ranges for all of the regions in that geography.

This is not necessarily true that your organization is in the same region as your agents. They are in the same geography.

But answering you question this is not possible to request for agent for another region. So if you need that you need to consider self hosted agents on your won infrastracture. You can create several agent pools and handle them to support your need.

Comment: Thanks for the response Krzysztof. I'm hoping to keep the resource group in the desired region and create the resources in eastus2, where our organizations' devops region, at least for now.